# Python: How to mock a call that accepts a list argument and assert the first item of the list arg

Tags: python, mocking

I'm using python mock and have a unit test where I need to ensure a function was called and the first element of this is a particular value. Consider this short example:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch, ANY

class foo():
    def something(self, a, b):
        print a,b

class footest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testany(self):
        f = foo()
        with patch.object(f, "something", autospec=True) as mock_something:
            f.something(1, [2,3,4])
            mock_something.assert_called_with(ANY, [2, ANY])

unittest.main()
```

Certainly this fails because I passed a three element list instead of a two element list. I can resolve this by going through mock_something.calls myself and pulling apart the arguments, but I'm wondering if any built in mock feature exists that would easily allow me to assert that the list can contain any number of ANYs?

Comment: I am not sure but I don't remember such a thing. But you just want to assert its a list, and the first element is 2. I would just do what you said you can do to resolve it, being explcit.

Comment: There is no feature in mock to do that. You're assuming that mock is going to inspect the argument, but it doesn't have this attribution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested with `mock.call_args`

Link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
from mock import patch, ANY

class foo():
    def something(self, a, b):
        print(a, b)

class footest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testany(self):
        f = foo()
        with patch.object(f, "something", autospec=True) as mock_something:
            f.something(1, [2,3,4])
            # mock_something.assert_called_with(ANY, [2, ANY])
            assert mock_something.call_count == 1

            received_args = mock_something.call_args.args
            target_arg = received_args[1]
            assert target_arg[0] == 2

            print("Result of mock_something.call_args", mock_something.call_args)
            print("Result of mock_something.call_args.args", mock_something.call_args.args)

unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
(venv) nponcian 2020_7Jul_14_StackOVerflowPytest$ ./script.py 
Result of mock_something.call_args call(1, [2, 3, 4])
Result of mock_something.call_args.args (1, [2, 3, 4])
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```